# Is there any way to log the url and hash fragment in a single page application

Tags: javascript, php, backbone.js, slim

I'm developing a single page application with a PHP backend using [Slim Framework](http://goo.gl/VskLJa) and a JavaScript frontend client using [Backbone.js](http://goo.gl/D4G7Wq) and came across a situation where I want to log requests that result in a 404 error but knowing that hash fragments are not recorded in the request on the backend. I'm wondering if there is a work-around.

My first thoughts was to have JavaScript write a cookie with the hash fragment and have PHP read that for logging.

For logging I'm using a custom [Monolog](http://goo.gl/kMcdcX) handler for [Doctrine 2](http://goo.gl/HmqYMI).

Comment: What is the logging facility?

Comment: I updated the question -- Im using [Monolog](http://goo.gl/Lf5xK1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use for sending those fragments off to Google Analytics or off to my error reporting system:

```
    var url = Backbone.history.getFragment();

    if (!/^\//.test(url)) {
        url = "/" + url;    
    }
```

Comment: Oh...unless I read it too fast and you can't actually get the fragment when you get a 404?

Comment: After writing the question it dawned on me that for clicks that result in "not found" event I can get the url/fragment and send that information to the server.